# how to get the value and pass it another screen when click on edit icon

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to edit the data but all data is not getting from the display screen

I created a display screen and put an edit icon on that display screen

When I click on edit icon then I want to get below issue no but I am not able to get the issue no and store in **text label**

[Edit screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf3sV.png)

see the below display screen

[see image of display screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x533.png)

I am trying to get the issueno from display screen and store it in issueno(text label)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that would be to use variables.

When you click your button to move to a different screen, you can use the `Set()` function to store values. Put that code before `Navigate()`:

```
Set(varIssueNo, TextInputIssueNo.Text);
Navigate(NextScreen);
```

The function goes as `Set( VariableName, Value )`, where value could pretty much by of any DataType -> Text, Number, Object, ...

Then, on you NextScreen, you use the `varIssueNo` variable to display where you need it - a label for example.

You can join variables and Text/Numbers in Power Apps this way `$"Issue Number: {varIssueNo}"`